# Freezing and Crash in Excel 2010 When Formatting Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, freeze

After normal function for over a year, we began to experience a problem in Excel 2010 running on Windows 7.  When we try to format cells or change the font, we see a freezing or crashing behavior. Freezing is accompanied with a (not responding) message.  It will resolve in 30 seconds or so.  The problem is reliably reproduced  the first time we format cells after opening Excel the first time for the day.  After which, the freezing/crash is sporadic.  Uninstalling and reinstalling Office has not helped.

We still see the problem after disabling addins.  We do not see the problem in Safe Mode.

[image: Mid Freeze]

Comment: You keep using *we*, so does this involve multiple computers? Does this happen in all spreadsheets, or only with specific ones?

Comment: We have had 3 users complain about this.  Office is installed individually on each computer.  We uninstalled/reinstalled office on one computer with no improvement.